# How to test the return value of a promise in a Cucumber test?

Tags: asynchronous, cucumber, couchdb, axios, cucumberjs

I'm trying to test the return value of a get request to a couchdb node.

I have a feature defined with the following Given clause:

```
Given A get request is made to the DB
```

which is implemented with the following step function:

```
var Profile = require('../UserProfile.js')
Given('A get request is made to the DB', function () {

    var text = Profile.getDB('localhost:5984').then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })

});
```

The above step references this model:

```
var axios = require('axios')

module.exports = {

    getDB: function(url){               
        return axios.get(url).then(response => {
            return response.data
        })

    }
};
```

I can't seem to log the result of the GET request when I perform it in the model and reference it in the step definition.  When I do the GET request in the step definition, it works - but this isn't useful to me, I want to test the model.  How do I get the resulting value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cucumber 2.0 supports Promises as returns](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/master/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md#step-definitions), try with:

```
const Profile = require('../UserProfile')
const { defineSupportCode } = require('cucumber')

defineSupportCode(({ defineStep }) => {
   defineStep('A get request is made to the DB', function () {
      return Profile.getDB('http://localhost:5984').then(data => {
        console.log(data)
      })
   })
})
```